# Borrar documentos relacionados nodejs mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo los siguientes modelos relacionados productInfo con el modelo Image, pero no se como hacer para cuando elimino un documento del modelo productInfo  se eliminen tambien los documentos relacionados del modelo Image, pensé que si le agregaba populate funcionaría pero no, creo que debo indicarle que ids eliminar o algo así pero no se como.

Gracias por la ayuda

```
    const productInfoSchema = new Schema({
        brand: String,
        model: String,
        color: String,
        views: {type: Number, default: 0},
        fuelType: String,
        price: Number,
        description: String,
        cylinder_capacity: Number,
        timestamp: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        image: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Image'}]
    });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('productInfo', productInfoSchema);
    
    
    
    const ImageSchema = new Schema({
        file_name: String,
    });
    
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);


ctrl.delete = async(req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    let delete_car = await productInfo.deleteOne({_id: id}).populate('image');
    console.log(delete_car);
    res.redirect('/getCars')
    
}
```

En el controlador

```
const productInfo = require('../models/productInfo');
const Image = require('../models/image');
//llamando el schema
var productInfoSchema = require('mongoose').model('productInfo').schema;

ctrl.delete = async(req, res) => {

productInfoSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    Image.remove({ _id: { $in: this.image } }).exec();
    next();
});


const id = req.params.id;
// console.log(id);
let delete_car = await productInfo.deleteOne({_id: id});
console.log(delete_car);
res.redirect('/getCars')

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra solución es realizar una búsqueda del documento que se desea eliminar en la colección productInfo para obtener los ObjectId de los documentos de la colección Image relacionados, para proceder a eliminarlos también. Para ello, sus modelos quedan inalterados, únicamente necesita cambiar su controlador y ruta:

#### Controlador

```javascript
const productInfo = require('../models/productInfo')
const Image = require('../models/image')

const ctrl = {}

ctrl.delete = async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id
  const item = await productInfo.findById(id)
  const deletedImages = await Image.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: item.image } })
  const deletedCar = await productInfo.deleteOne({ _id: id })
  console.log({ deletedImages, deletedCar })
  res.redirect('/getCars')
}
```

#### Ruta

```javascript
router.get('/deleteProduct/:id', edit_produts.delete);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar un borrado en cascada con Mongoose puedes utilizar el siguiente pre-hook para que este se encargue de eliminar el documento relacionado de la colección Image antes de borrar el de la colección productInfo.

```javascript
productInfoSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    Image.remove({ _id: { $in: this.image } }).exec();
    next();
});
```

NOTA: Agrego el operador $in porque veo que la propiedad image dentro del schema productInfo es un arreglo de tipo ObjectId. Si fuera una única referencia sería solo { _id: this.image }

- Referencia: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349259/11303292\](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349259/11303292%5C)
- Relacionado: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

Comment: Hola  Llamé el schema así var productInfoSchema = require('mongoose').model('productInfo').schema; y aplique el prehook dentro de l afuncion ctrl.delete así  productInfoSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
        Image.remove({ _id: { $in: this.image } }).exec();
        next();
    });    pero no me funciona. no da error, pero no funciona, creería que no encuentre el id que debe eliminar, edité la pregunta para mostrar lo que hice